# Consulta lenguaje C resultados raros

Tags: c

Alguien sabe porque me da como resultado esto??

Yo quiero esta secuencia

1° Pida el codigo numerico de proyecto
2° Lo muestro
3° Pida la cadena de caracter en nombre
4° La muestre
5° Pida el codigo numerico de categoria
6° Lo muestre
7° Si se dan las condiciones que la cadena es >=40 por ejemplo que vuelva a ingresar todo

Pero me da resultados raros y no me deja poner el dato de categoria p, es decir no llega.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char nombre[3][40];
    int proyecto[3],categoriap[3];
    int conttecnicas10y20[3];
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i=i+1)
    {
        printf("Ingrese codigo de proyecto, nombre del proyecto y categoria del proyecto\n");
        scanf("%d",&proyecto[i]);
        printf("%d",proyecto[i]);
        gets(nombre[i]);
        puts(nombre[i]);
        scanf("%d",&categoriap[i]); 
        printf("%d",categoriap[i]);
        conttecnicas10y20[i]=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Despues puse un while que si la longitud de la cadena de caracteres es >= 40 ingrese nuevamente los datos.

Ayuda!!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código va como texto, por favor edita tu pregunta y de paso haces el [tour]

Comment: Hola christian, quise poner el codigo pero me queda parte afuera...

Lo pongo como me queda, aunque no esté muy bien.

Comment: Pues sip, otras personas se encargarán de colocarlo bien

Comment: Ahí pusé el codigo

Comment: cuando tienen razon, tienen razon...

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que `scanf()` lee lo que se solicita, pero no lee el caracter `\n` que queda al final de la línea. Esto ocurre porque el caracter `\n` no es parte del número, por lo cual no se procesa.

Una forma de solucionar esto el leer todos los caracteres hasta el `\n` usando esto: `while (getchar() != '\n');`. Sin embargo, esta no es la única forma de solucionar el problema.

El código reparado (el cual imprime resultados intermedios) es este:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    char nombre[3][40];
    int proyecto[3],categoriap[3];
    int conttecnicas10y20[3];
    
    for(i=0;i<3;i=i+1)
    {
        printf("Ingrese codigo de proyecto, nombre del proyecto y categoria del proyecto\n");
        printf("Codigo: ");
        scanf("%d",&proyecto[i]);
        printf("%d\n",proyecto[i]);
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        printf("Nombre: ");
        gets(nombre[i]);
        printf("%s\n", nombre[i]);
        printf("Categoria: ");
        scanf("%d",&categoriap[i]); 
        printf("%d\n",categoriap[i]);
        while (getchar() != '\n');
        conttecnicas10y20[i]=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Es decir usando "while getchar...." estamos diciendo que mientras leyamos todo excepto los '\n' continue?

Comment: La idea es leer todos los caracteres,  hasta que se lea un /n

Comment: Tendrías algún apunte sobre este tema que me gustaria profundizar?